# lambda function with rank

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset is as follows,

| index | advance to deposit |
| --- | --- |
| company1 | 86.8% |
| company2 | 96.2% |

I tried with following code,

```
bank_ratios['rank3'] = bank_ratios['Advance to Deposit'].apply(lambda x:0 if x>100%  or x<85%  else `rank(ascending=False))`
```

I want to rank the company based on the value, but I want to return a value 0 if <80% or >100%, if it is in between, rank the company.

In this code it says invalid syntax. Here I used the this column as object.

How to set the condition using lambda?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the percentage as float

```
df['advance_percentage'] = df['advance to deposit'].str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
```

Get rank column

```
df['rank3'] = np.where(
    df.advance_percentage.between(80, 100), 
    df.advance_percentage.rank(ascending=False),
    0
)
```